# Difference between import audio file and expo-av getURI()

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I am trying to use an very simple expo audio player from [this repo](https://github.com/olapiv/expo-audio-player)
the player works fine with audio files imported as

`import AudioFile from '../assets/test.m4a';`

console.log of AudioFile returns a number

```
console.log(typeof AudioFile);
```

but when i try to use a file uri that i receive from a recorder i get a uri for the file as follows and the player does not work

```
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540madaher%252Fdelivery/Audio/recording-091d5e42-1a82-4e59-8e76-d415ca424c29.m4a
```

Can someone help me understand the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing
`await this.soundObject.loadAsync({ uri: this.props.audio })`; instead of `await this.soundObject.loadAsync(this.props.audio);`
Hope this helps somebody